# ionic version problem and Unexpected end of json input ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

As i was using ionic3. Ionic auto v4 updated and now i get this error " Unexpected end of JSON input"

i using mysql beckend

i changed ionic version 4 to 3.4 , but still i get same error. how can fix it

I unable to solve it ,anyone know please teach me i will appreciate~

login.ts

```
login(){
   if(this.userData.username && this.userData.password){
    this.authService.postData(this.userData, "login").then((result) =>{
    this.resposeData = result;
```

auth.service.ts

```
 postData(credentials, type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
      subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) =>{
        reject(err);
      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: anyone help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the unexpected end of json input problem. no need of promise with v4 but another problem occurred.

If i start project on development mod on web or mobile i get this error

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://katalog.forev.com.tr/PHP-Slim-Restful-master/api/login with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I used chrome extension allow control allow origin but it didnt work
And my php beckend sql header conf.

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers " content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
There was no such error in the ioniv v3

I generate android apk and try on apk, no error . work well. i really understand.